# Replace Middleware Pattern with Observable (subscriptions cancel?)

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

There is common approach to use middlewares in a lot of frameworks.

In [ExpressJS](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/dc538f6e810bd462c98ee7e6aae24c64d4b1da93/examples/web-service/index.js#L28) - here I handle request with `middleware-chain`:

```
app.use('/url', middleware1);
app.use('/url', middleware2);
app.use('/url', middleware3);
```

In [Telegraf](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/blob/7bc00991af6d4ca82fb3a13c75ec05e2882a8671/docs/examples/koa-webhook-bot.js#L10) - here I handle message event (as a bot) with `middleware-chain`:

```
bot.on('text', middleware1);
bot.on('text', middleware2);
bot.on('text', middleware3);
```

Above examples work, util I want to implement to postpone some requests/events. In this case if my `middleware-chain` is busy handling some request/event at the moment - I can store new incoming events/requests in DB and handle it later when my `middleware-chain` will be free. The main reason of this is to restrict for some users to send only one request/event at the time and wait to response if `middleware-chain` is busy.

Let's assume that I can store/retrieve anything I need in/from DB. However if I retrieved some request/event from DB - I want to send/pass this request/event through all my middlewares. In this case I need to reimplement event bubbling if framework is not support this.

However I can use Observable for this.

ExpressJS:

```
const sbj = new Subject();

app.use('/url', (...args) => {
  sbj.next(args)
});

observable.subscribe({
  next: middleware1
});
observable.subscribe({
  next: middleware2
});
observable.subscribe({
  next: middleware3
});
```

Telegraf:

```
const sbj = new Subject();

bot.on('text', (...args) => {
  sbj.next(args)
});

observable.subscribe({
  next: middleware1
});
observable.subscribe({
  next: middleware2
});
observable.subscribe({
  next: middleware3
});
```

But I am missing one important feature in `Observable-chain` that I have in `middleware-chain` => in `middleware-chain` I can cancel next middlewares. E.g. `middleware1 -> next -> middleware2 -> cancel`.

How can I achieve the same behaviour with `Observable` (so one subscription can cancel another)? I think there should be elegant solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RxJS has its own "chaining" mechanism called **pipeable operators**. There is a whole range of those available to you [as you can see here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/). If you have reusable middleware you can very well implement those as your own operators. For example, an authentication operator could look like this:

```
function authenticator() = (obs$) => obs$.pipe(
  mergeMap(([req, res]) => req.isAuthenticated() ? of([req, res]) : throwError([res, "Must be authenticated!"]))
)
```

Then, you can use it as follows:

```
const sbj = new Subject();

app.use('/url', (...args) => {
  sbj.next(args)
});

sbj.pipe(
   authenticator(),
   // more operators
).subscribe(([req, res]) => {
   // send response
}, ([res, err]) => {
   // send error
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Without observable express provide a next('route') for you to skip the middleware chain
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

```
var app = express()
var router = express.Router()

// predicate the router with a check and bail out when needed
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.headers['x-auth']) return next('router')
  next()
})

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello, user!')
})

// use the router and 401 anything falling through
app.use('/admin', router, function (req, res) {
  res.sendStatus(401)
})
```